# HTTP redirect to HTTPS while keeping angular routes (.htaccess)

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess, http, redirect, https

All I want to do is preventing the site for going http rather than https. Here is my .htaccess configuration. Only www.mywebsite.com and mywebsite.com doesn't go https. Angular routes are ok too. If i write mywebsite.com/signup it goes https as well. What should i do to be able to redirect all scenarios to https ?

**SCENARIOS:**

www.website.com          -> not https

website.com              -> not https

website.com/signin       -> https

www.website.com/signin   -> https

```
RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
  RewriteRule ^ - [L]


  RewriteRule ^ /
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first 2 rewrite conditions will ignore existing files and directories, but the root directory (normally) always exists. Try to remove the first block.

This will be sufficient:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

For angular routes to work you need another block like this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

That way all non SSL traffic will be redirected. The second part will rewrite everything to your angular index file, except existing directories and files

Comment: without them my routes are inaccessible. i got 404. and if i only write website.com i got 500

Comment: I can t reach my routes with that. navigating through main page is OK but if i refresh the page or enter www.mywebsite.com/route1 i got 404

Comment: I tried the above and get an error: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS  Can someone verify both these work together?

Comment: I've used both blocks in my .htaccess file, but when I go to a route via url, I've got Internal server error. If I click on a link in the app, it works fine.